# JavaFX won't show my cards in gameboard if i dont call the method in initialize()

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm having problem with showing gamecards on my gameboard. It's like it won't "render" the images if I dont do it in the initialize() method from JavaFX.

Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/menu/menu.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("This is not a chess inspired game!!");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1920, 1080));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

MenuController:

```
public class MenuController {


    @FXML
    private Pane menuPane;

    public void startGame() throws IOException {
        Pane tableViewPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/tableview/tableview.fxml"));
        menuPane.getChildren().setAll(tableViewPane);

    }

    public void viewHighscore() throws IOException {
        Pane highscorePane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/highscore/highscore.fxml"));
        menuPane.getChildren().setAll(highscorePane);
    }

    public void quitGame() {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

TableViewController:

```
@FXML
private HBox playerOneHandBox;
@FXML
private HBox playerTwoHandBox;
@FXML
private AnchorPane cardPane;

private Server server;
private Deck deck; 

public TableViewController() throws IOException {
    deck = new Deck();
    server = Server.getInstance();
}

public void showPlayerHand(List<String> commands) throws IOException {
    try {
        deck.getCardsFromJSON(); // gets all cards (50)
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String player = commands.get(1);
    for (int i = 2; i < commands.size(); i++) {
        Card card = deck.getCards().get(Integer.parseInt(commands.get(i)));
        System.out.println(card.getId());
        String cardURL = "/card/card.fxml";
        switch (player) {
            case "1":
                // player1 gets 5 cards to her hand, from her deck
                cardPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(cardURL));
                playerOneHandBox.getChildren().add(cardPane);
                playerOneHandBox.setSpacing(50);
                playerOneHandBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                cardPane.setId(String.valueOf(card.getId()));
                System.out.println(cardPane);
                //TODO: Code for showing card in FX for player 1
                break;
            case "2":
                //player 2 gets 5 cards on her hand from her deck.
                cardPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(cardURL));
                playerOneHandPane.getChildren().add(cardPane);
                playerTwoHandBox.setSpacing(50);
                playerTwoHandBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                cardPane.setId(String.valueOf(card.getId()));
                System.out.println(cardPane);
                //TODO: Code for showing card in FX for player 2
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("No player! Something wrong with string input from gameEngine");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

tableView.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Glow?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Circle?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<Pane fx:id="tableViewPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="1080.0" prefWidth="1920.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.TableViewController">
    <children>
        <ImageView fx:id="tableImageView" fitHeight="1080.0" fitWidth="1920.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <image>
                <Image url="@gameboard.jpg" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
      <HBox fx:id="playerOneHandBox" layoutX="451.0" layoutY="767.0" prefHeight="224.0" prefWidth="973.0" />
      <HBox fx:id="playerTwoHandBox" layoutX="546.0" layoutY="91.0" prefHeight="207.0" prefWidth="830.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerOneTableOne" fx:id="playerOneTableOne" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="899.0" layoutY="556.0" opacity="0.5" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="125.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerOneTableFour" fx:id="playerOneTableFour" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="1170.0" layoutY="556.0" opacity="0.5" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="125.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerOneTableTwo" fx:id="playerOneTableTwo" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="1034.0" layoutY="556.0" opacity="0.5" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="125.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerOneTableThree" fx:id="playerOneTableThree" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="763.0" layoutY="556.0" opacity="0.5" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="125.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerOneTableFive" fx:id="playerOneTableFive" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="626.0" layoutY="556.0" opacity="0.5" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="125.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerOneTableSix" fx:id="playerOneTableSix" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="1305.0" layoutY="556.0" opacity="0.5" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="125.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerOneTableSeven" fx:id="playerOneTableSeven" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="491.0" layoutY="556.0" opacity="0.5" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="125.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerTwoTableSix" fx:id="playerTwoTableSix" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="492.0" layoutY="341.0" opacity="0.5" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="125.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerTwoTableSeven" fx:id="playerTwoTableSeven" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="1306.0" layoutY="341.0" opacity="0.5" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="125.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerTwoTableFour" fx:id="playerTwoTableFour" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="627.0" layoutY="341.0" opacity="0.5" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="125.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerTwoTableTwo" fx:id="playerTwoTableTwo" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="764.0" layoutY="341.0" opacity="0.5" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="125.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerTwoTableThree" fx:id="playerTwoTableThree" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="1035.0" layoutY="341.0" opacity="0.5" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="125.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerTwoTableFive" fx:id="playerTwoTableFive" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="1171.0" layoutY="341.0" opacity="0.5" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="125.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerTwoTableOne" fx:id="playerTwoTableOne" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="900.0" layoutY="341.0" opacity="0.5" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="125.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerTwoDeck" fx:id="playerTwoDeck" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="326.0" layoutY="52.0" rotate="45.0" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="108.0" />
        <Rectangle id="playerOneDeck" fx:id="playerOneDeck" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="500.0" fill="#1f93ff00" height="175.0" layoutX="326.0" layoutY="853.0" rotate="135.0" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="108.0" />
        <Button id="endTurn" fx:id="endTurn" layoutX="1560.0" layoutY="516.0" mnemonicParsing="false" opacity="0.5" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="End Turn" />
        <Label id="playerOneHp" fx:id="playerOneHp" layoutX="1527.0" layoutY="603.0" text="20" textFill="#ffffffcc">
            <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="64.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <Label id="playerTwoHp" fx:id="playerTwoHp" layoutX="1527.0" layoutY="384.0" text="20" textFill="#ffffffcd">
            <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="64.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <Circle fill="#00000080" layoutX="1605.0" layoutY="301.0" radius="37.0" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle fill="#000000b8" layoutX="1606.0" layoutY="781.0" radius="37.0" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle id="playerOneGraveyard" fx:id="playerOneGraveyard" fill="#ffffff8a" layoutX="1569.0" layoutY="960.0" radius="100.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <Circle id="playerTwoGraveyard" fx:id="playerTwoGraveyard" fill="#ffffff8a" layoutX="1569.0" layoutY="124.0" radius="100.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
        <ProgressBar id="playerOneMana" fx:id="playerOneMana" layoutX="695.0" layoutY="1026.0" opacity="0.8" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="530.0" progress="1.0">
            <effect>
                <Glow level="0.65" />
            </effect>
        </ProgressBar>
        <ProgressIndicator id="playerOneHpRound" fx:id="playerOneHpRound" blendMode="RED" layoutX="1507.0" layoutY="608.0" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="115.0" progress="0.28" />
        <ProgressIndicator id="playerTwoHpRound" fx:id="playerTwoHpRound" blendMode="RED" layoutX="1507.0" layoutY="391.0" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="115.0" progress="0.28" />
        <ProgressBar id="playerTwoMana" fx:id="playerTwoMana" layoutX="697.0" layoutY="24.0" opacity="0.8" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="530.0" progress="1.0">
            <effect>
                <Glow level="0.65" />
            </effect>
        </ProgressBar>
        <ImageView id="winner" fx:id="winner" fitHeight="539.0" fitWidth="1019.0" layoutX="451.0" layoutY="328.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
            <image>
                <Image url="@WinnerScreen.png" />
            </image>
            <effect>
                <Glow level="0.65" />
            </effect>
        </ImageView>
        <ImageView id="PlayerTwoTurn" fx:id="PlayerTwoTurn" fitHeight="279.0" fitWidth="141.0" layoutX="1536.0" layoutY="114.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
            <image>
                <Image url="@Fire_GIF.gif" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
        <ImageView id="PlayerOneTurn" fx:id="PlayerOneTurn" fitHeight="279.0" fitWidth="141.0" layoutX="1536.0" layoutY="595.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
            <image>
                <Image url="@Fire_GIF.gif" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </children>
</Pane>
```

All the rectangles are just placeholders for now so ignore them!
The code above wont add the pictures to HBox, but this will:

```
public void initialize() throws IOException {
    cardPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/card/card.fxml"));
    playerOneHandBox.getChildren().add(cardPane);
}
```

Card.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="cardPane" onMouseClicked="#getSelectedCard" prefHeight="175.0" prefWidth="125.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.CardController">
    <children>
        <Label layoutX="45.0" layoutY="29.0" text="KORT" />
        <Label layoutX="37.0" layoutY="100.0" text="ATTACK" />
        <Label layoutX="53.0" layoutY="68.0" text="HP" />
      <ImageView fx:id="cardImageView" fitHeight="175.0" fitWidth="125.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This method is from my "server" class and it gives fx the id's of the cards. Then in method showPlayerHand() in TableViewController I compare the id's i got from the server and creates them in showPlayerHand().

```
    public void initGame() throws IOException {
        deck.createFullDeck();
        initPlayer();

        String player1hand = getStringFromList(p2.getPlayerHand());
        String player2hand = getStringFromList(p1.getPlayerHand());
        server.msgToFX("showplayerhand,1,"+player1hand);
        server.msgToFX("showplayerhand,2,"+player2hand);
 }
```

Output from showPlayerHand() method:

```
1. for FX
2. for Console
1
starting game
Player1: 0,4,31,18,1,
Player2: 30,37,46,41,34,
=== Call to showPlayerHand() in FX for Player1 ===
CardId 0/  imgURL: /cardpics/Card1.png AnchorPane[id=0]
CardId 4/  imgURL: /cardpics/Card1.png AnchorPane[id=4]
CardId 31/  imgURL: /cardpics/Card4.png AnchorPane[id=31]
CardId 18/  imgURL: /cardpics/Card2.png AnchorPane[id=18]
CardId 1/  imgURL: /cardpics/Card1.png AnchorPane[id=1]
=== Call to showPlayerHand() in FX for Player2 ===
CardId 30/  imgURL: /cardpics/Card4.png AnchorPane[id=30]
CardId 37/  imgURL: /cardpics/Card4.png AnchorPane[id=37]
CardId 46/  imgURL: /cardpics/Card5.png AnchorPane[id=46]
CardId 41/  imgURL: /cardpics/Card5.png AnchorPane[id=41]
CardId 34/  imgURL: /cardpics/Card4.png AnchorPane[id=34]
```

How come? I can't figure it out on my own... I've been stuck for two days with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not including `card.fxml` anywhere in `tableView.fxml` so how do you expect it to show up? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Gnas sry, I updated the post -> I added Card.fxml and objects in TableViewController. Does it makes sense now or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Is `showPlayerHand` the method you use to display the cards? If so where do you call it? I don't you call it anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Gnas I edited the post again with new information, the communication between FX and Server are working fine. The problem is that the images only shows on the tableview if I call it in initialize(), but I need to do it dynamically. With other methods to :/

Comment: Can you verify that `showPlayerHand` gets called with correct parameters?

Comment: @Gnas updated post with output when i press "start game" in menu.

Comment: Does it throw any exception or it just doesn't show the cards?

Comment: It just doesnt show the Cards, it Will render stuff in initialize but not other things :/. Any ideas?

Comment: As a suggestion to track down the issue, at the begining of `showPlayerHand` add a `Label` control with some random text and see if it is displayed. If it is then the problem is in the loop and possibly the switch statement, otherwise it's something to do with your server-client interaction.

Comment: @Gnas it doesnt show the label either...